# How to set height of rich html editor component

Tags: angular, quill

I am using the rich html editor Quill in my angular component. My question is how can I set the height of the editing area.

I am using angular-7, bootstrap and font-awesome (all latest)

I can not find anything in the documentation for this.

thanks

Johan

Below is my form and an example of the form

```
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && onSubmit()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="htmlContent">Content</label>
    <quill-editor id="editor" name="htmlContent" [(ngModel)]="model.htmlContent" #htmlContent="ngModel">
    </quill-editor>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary mr-2">Opslaan</button>
    <button (click)="cancel()" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">Annuleer</button>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this for e.g:

```
 [style]="{height: '250px'}"
```

to your quill-editor

```
<quill-editor id="editor" name="htmlContent" [(ngModel)]="model.htmlContent" 
[style]="{height: '250px'}" #htmlContent="ngModel">
```

Comment: @baliman doesn't want to accept the answer? is there any problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could always inspect the element to see which classes are bind to it. Quill has the `.ql-editor` for its text area. So, it would look like:

```
.ql-snow .ql-editor{height: 500px;}
```